# Como acrescentar Divs a partir de um numero passado do Select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Poderiam me ajudar com um problema que estou tendo?

Bom gente preciso criar um select com valores de 1 a N numeros, após o usuário selecionar um numero no select tem que criar n divs a partir do valor selecionado.

Segue o exemplo não funcionando ...

```js
$("#qtdLote").on("change",function(){
    var num=parseInt($(this).val());
    
    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++){ // se não houver valor o loop não roda.
      $("#area").append("<div> Div "+i+"</div>");
      // Append adiciona ao final do elemento desejado.
    }
    
 });
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Escolha</label>
<select id="qtdLote">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>


<div id="#area" ></div>
```

Pode ver também no codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZYdjv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop com o valor do select.

```js
$(function(){
  // Use desta forma caso suas divs fiquem dentro de um elemento apenas para elas:
  $("#seletor").on("change",function(){
    var num=parseInt($(this).val());
    
    $("#area").html(""); // Limpar o elemento pai.
    
    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++){ // se não houver valor o loop não roda.
      $("#area").append("<div> Div "+i+"</div>");
      // Append adiciona ao final do elemento desejado.
    }
    
  });
    
  // Caso contrário você vai precisar identificar as divs criadas
  // como dar uma classe para elas. Vou colocar um exemplo abaixo.
  
  $("#seletor-com-classe").on("change",function(){
    var num=parseInt($(this).val());
    
    $(".criadoDinamicamente").remove(); // Remover divs.
    
    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++){ // se não houver valor o loop não roda.
      $("#area").append("<div class='criadoDinamicamente'> Div "+i+"</div>");
      // Append adiciona ao final do elemento desejado.
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
#area{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
#area div{
  flex-grow:1;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="seletor">
  <option value="">Quantas divs criar?</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
</select>

<div id="area"></div>
```

Comment: Opa Henrique, Muito Obrigado pela ajuda mas esta quase certo, exemplo se ele escolheu 2 aparece 2, ai no caso se ele escolher 3 aparece 3 e se ele escolher 1 aparece só uma,  ele mostra e esconde a partir do valor dado, pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Creio que entendi, editei o meu código ali para você ver como ficaria, tem 2 opções ali que podem lhe ser úteis

Comment: Caraaamba Henrique era isso Mesmo !!! Muuuito Obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Já tem uma resposta que lhe atende em termos de solução, mas é sempre importante percebermos os nossos erros para podermos evoluir e não os cometer no futuro.

Este é o seu código Javascript:

```
$("#qtdLote").on("change",function(){
    var num=parseInt($(this).val());

    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++){
      $("#area").append("<div> Div "+i+"</div>");
    }
 });
```

Na verdade tá muito perto de estar a funcionar como pretende. O primeiro problema vem no html de facto, pois `$("#area")` não acerta no elemento que devia porque você definiu ele com um `#` a mais:

```
<div id="#area" ></div>
<!--     ^          -->
```

Retirando o `#` para ficar `id="area"` já preenche os elementos, de acordo com o que seleciona. Mas acaba por não limpar os anteriores cada vez que escolhe outra opção. Pode fazer isso adicionando um `$("#area").html('');` antes do `for`.

A unica coisa que fica a faltar é correr o código mal inicia, que consegue fazer apenas com mais uma instrução, apos o código que já tem:

```
$("#qtdLote").trigger("change");
```

O [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) força programaticamente o evento passado como parâmetro, neste caso o `change`, como se tivesse sido o usuário a faze-lo.

Veja o seu código com essas 3 pequenas alterações a funcionar:

```js
$("#qtdLote").on("change",function(){
    var num=parseInt($(this).val());
    $("#area").html(''); //limpar antes de gerar
    for(var i=1;i<=num;i++){
      $("#area").append("<div> Div "+i+"</div>");
    }
 });
 
$("#qtdLote").trigger("change"); //forçar o trigger para quando abre a página
```

```css
div{ border:1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Escolha</label>
<select id="qtdLote">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<div id="area" ></div> <!-- id corrigido-->
```